# Shiny: renderText fails with conditional slidebar

Tags: shiny

I am trying to learn Shiny and I am banging my head on a problem.

I cannot render as text a value determined with a `sliderInput` if this is inside a conditional panel. Just can't understand how to fix this problem.

Minimal example

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Plot my distribution"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Plot a distribution."),

  selectInput("distr", 
              label = "Choose a distribution",
              choices = c("Binomial", 
                          "Negative Binomial",
                          "Poisson"),
              selected = "Binomial"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.distr != 'Poisson'",
    sliderInput("prob", 
                label = "Probability of success:",
                min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5
    )
  )
),  
mainPanel(
  textOutput("selected_dist"),
  textOutput("prob")
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$selected_dist <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$distr)
  })

  output$prob <- reactive({
    renderText({ 
      paste("You have chosen probability =", input$prob)
    })
  })
  outputOptions(output, "prob", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If the slider is not conditional it works. What's missing in the reactive command? The `outputOption` command  I found in a tutorial, but doesn't mak any difference.

I get the following output

> You have selected Binomial
>   structure(function (...) ,{, if (length(outputArgs) != 0 && !hasExecuted$get()) {, warning("Unused argument: outputArgs. The argument outputArgs is only ", , "meant to be used when embedding snippets of Shiny code in an ", , "R Markdown code chunk (using runtime: shiny). When running a ", , "full Shiny app, please set the output arguments directly in ", , "the corresponding output function of your UI code."), hasExecuted$set(TRUE), }, if (is.null(formals(origRenderFunc))) , origRenderFunc(), else origRenderFunc(...),}, class = "function", outputFunc = function (outputId, container = if (inline) span else div, , inline = FALSE) ,{, container(id = outputId, class = "shiny-text-output"),}, outputArgs = list(), hasExecuted = )

[image]

Comment: If your `selectInput` is `"distr"` shouldn't  `condition = "input.distr  ...."` too,  and not `condition = "input.distrib...`?

Comment: Yes, right. But that was a typo in the question (sorry). fixed.

Comment: removing the reactive tag from `output$prob` solves the issue for me.

Comment: @novica yes, it does. I am really confused about the eactive environments! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two reactive UIs here, one for the slider and another for the text. But only one responds to the `condition`, the slider. You want both to depend on `input$distr`. One way to do this is to render text only when `input$distr != Poisson`.

Also, I think there is a recommendation that  `render` statements should not be inside `reactive` statements or the other way around. because a `render` statement is already reactive.

So, to show the value selected through the slider as text only when the slider widget is rendered, you can do:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$selected_dist <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$distr)
})


output$prob <- renderText({
    if (!input$distr== "Poisson") {
        paste("You have chosen probability =", input$prob)
    }
})
}
```